# Firebase notification click Intent show null on Background state - Xamarin.forms Android

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my xamarin.forms app I have used Firebase Push notifications. In the android portion I can receive notification on both `Foreground ,background and killed state`. The problem I am facing is when I tap the notification in background state or killed state, I cant get the values from `Intent`; It shows null. This was working perfectly earlier, I can't figure out what I have done wrong. I can get the values of notification when app is in foreground mode.

**My FirebaseMessagingService**

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService

{
    // private string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    public static string EmployeeID = "";
    public static string StartDate = "";
    public static string NotificationType = "";
    public static string TotalHours = "";
    public static string EmployeeName = "";
    public static string EmployeeNumber = "";
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        base.OnMessageReceived(message);
        try
        {
            SendNotification(message.GetNotification().Body, message.GetNotification().Title, message.Data);
            EmployeeID = message.Data["EmpID"].ToString();
            StartDate = message.Data["SDate"].ToString();
            NotificationType = message.Data["NotificationType"].ToString();
            TotalHours = message.Data["TotalHours"].ToString();
            EmployeeName = message.Data["EmployeeName"].ToString();
            EmployeeNumber = message.Data["EmpNo"].ToString();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

    }
    private void SendNotification(string messageBody, string messageTitle, IDictionary<string, string> data)
    {

        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.PutExtra("user_notification_id", EmployeeID);

        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        foreach (var key in data.Keys)
        {
            intent.PutExtra(key, data[key]);
        }
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, new Random().Next(), intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
        var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID).SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon_logo).SetContentTitle(messageTitle).SetContentText(messageBody).SetAutoCancel(true).SetContentIntent(pendingIntent).SetVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000 }).SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification)).SetStyle((new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().BigText(messageBody)));
        var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this); notificationManager.Notify(new Random().Next(), notificationBuilder.Build());

    }

}
```

**Main Activity**

```
namespace App.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "App", Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = false ]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        static readonly string TAG = "MainActivity";
        internal static readonly string CHANNEL_ID = "my_notification_channel";
        internal static readonly int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;
        private bool isNotification = false;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {    
            IsPlayServicesAvailable(); //You can use this method to check if play services are available.
            CreateNotificationChannel();// Notification channel is required for Android 8.0 + to receive notifications.        
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);                              
            
            // Here Iam getting Intent values as null on background or killed state
            
                if (Intent.Extras != null)
                {
                    foreach (var key in Intent.Extras.KeySet())
                    {
                        if (key != null)
                        {
                            var value = Intent.Extras.GetString(key);
                            string EmployeeID = Intent.Extras.GetString("EmpID");
                            string startDate = Intent.Extras.GetString("SDate");
                            string NotificationType = Intent.Extras.GetString("NotificationType");
                            string EmployeeName = Intent.Extras.GetString("EmployeeName");
                            string TotalHours = Intent.Extras.GetString("TotalHours");
                            string EmpNo = Intent.Extras.GetString("EmpNo");
                            LoadApplication(new App(true, EmployeeID, startDate, NotificationType, EmployeeName, TotalHours, EmpNo));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {                 LoadApplication(new App(isNotification));
                }
                
        }

        // <-------------- Notification click management in foregorund mode--->
        protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent != null)
            {
                var message = intent.GetStringExtra("EmpID");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                {
                    string EmployeeID = intent.GetStringExtra("EmpID");
                    string startDate = intent.GetStringExtra("SDate");
                    string NotificationType = intent.GetStringExtra("NotificationType");
                    string EmployeeName = intent.GetStringExtra("EmployeeName");
                    string TotalHours = intent.GetStringExtra("TotalHours");
                    string EmpNo = intent.GetStringExtra("EmpNo");
                    LoadApplication(new App(true, EmployeeID, startDate, NotificationType, EmployeeName, TotalHours, EmpNo));
                }
            }
            base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        }

        //<-------------- Checking whether google play service is availabe for fcm-------------------->
        public bool IsPlayServicesAvailable()
        {
            int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this); if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.Success)
            {
                if (GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsUserResolvableError(resultCode))
                {

                }
                // msgText.Text = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.GetErrorString(resultCode);
                else
                {
                    //This device is not supported           
                    Finish(); // Kill the activity if you want.         
                }
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Google Play Services is available.         
                return true;
            }
        }

        void CreateNotificationChannel()
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
                // support library). There is no need to create a notification 
                // channel on older versions of Android.
                return;
            }

            var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "FCM Notifications", NotificationImportance.High)
            {
                Description = "Firebase Cloud Messages appear in this channel",
            };
            channel.EnableVibration(true);
            channel.EnableLights(true);
            channel.LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public;
            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

    }
}
```

I am using Xamarin.forms version `4.6.0.800`  and `Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging` version `71.1740.4`. Any help is appreciated

**Edit**

The issue was related to the SplashScreen I have. When I removed the SplashActivty, and set `MainLauncher` is `True` for MainActivity, the issue solved. I can get the Intent value even if App closed. So how can I solve the issue with Splashscreen ? Should I pass the Intent to MainActivty from SplashActivity?

My `SplashActivity`

```
[Activity(Label = "App", MainLauncher = true,
  LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop,
  ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait,
  Theme = "@style/splashscreen", NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity

    {

        static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(SplashActivity).Name;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
            {
                Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = StatusBarVisibility.Visible;
                Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            }

            InvokeMainActivity();
        }

        private void InvokeMainActivity()
        {
            var mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            mainActivityIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NoAnimation); //Add this line
            StartActivity(mainActivityIntent);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys for this silly question. The issue was whenever I click notification the Intent will pass to SplashActivity. I didn't passed the Intent from Splash To Main Activity. Thanks @Cahyo for your help.

I added this in `SplashActivity`

```
 private void InvokeMainActivity()
        {
            var mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            if (Intent.Extras != null)
            {
                mainActivityIntent.PutExtras(Intent.Extras);
            }
            mainActivityIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NoAnimation); //Add this line
            StartActivity(mainActivityIntent);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set `"click_action":"OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"` in your firebase payload.

And then flag your default activity with `IntentFilterAttribute`

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" }, Categories = new[] { "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" })]
```

with out click_action your notification don't know which activity to be started.

Note: `OPEN_ACTIVITY_1` you can change this value but what you should pay attention to is that this value must be the same between `Firebase` and `IntentFilter`.

Comment: I didn;t have click_action property in Notification payload earlier and it were worked, WIll be there any other reason?

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. According to firebase notification docs "If a different Intent must be fired, the click_action field of the notification message must be set to that Intent (the launcher Intent is used when no click_action is specified)." So my doubt is if we don't use any specific click_action will the Intent.GetExtra will be null?